# PWA as sharing options for binary files

Tags: progressive-web-apps, sharing, manifest.json

I managed to add *share_target* section to my *PWA manifest.json* and everything works fine if I try to share a link: now I'd like to know if it's possible to share **files**, too.

I tried to setup the sharing section this way:

```
"share_target": {
    "action": "/share-target",
    "method": "post",
    "enctype": "multipart/form-data",
    "params": {
        "title": "title",
        "text": "text",
        "url": "url"
        }
    },
```

but it doesn't work: my PWA won't appear as a **sharing option** if I try to **share a pic from my android device gallery**.

Any suggestions appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved thanx to this tutorial: https://paul.kinlan.me/file-web-share-target/

I just had to change my code this way:

```
"share_target": {
"action": "/share/image/",
"method": "POST",
"enctype": "multipart/form-data",
"params": {
  "files": [
    {
      "name": "file",
      "accept": ["image/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

},

Comment: Note that browser support is limited.